# WPS office works fine, except context menu for new file creation on desktop

Tags: kde

I tried installing WPS office directly from the website after not being satisfied with the community versions from snap etc.

It worked like a charm and everything is working perfectly fine, except that the desktop context menu to create a new file results in the following error:

The file or folder /usr/share/templates/.source/wps演示文档.dps does not exist.

I reinstalled but to no avail. I even tried to rename the files from "/opt/kingsoft/wps-office/office6/asso_template/wps.dps" to  /usr/share/templates/.source/ - as wps演示文档.dps etc. but didn't work.

To give you some background, I'm had originally installed Ubuntu 18.04 and then later installed KDE Plasma and all associated apps - now while it boots, it says kubuntu. I also removed ubuntu-desktop package and a few others. I'm assuming I probably broke something while I converted to kubuntu?

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Finally after digging around, I found that the right click menu options are in /usr/share/templates and I found the incorrect links to the files. I just fixed them to /home/user/Templates/DOCX.docx etc. instead of /usr/share/templates/.source/ and problem solved!!