# Where can app specific right click contextual menu be altered?

Tags: 21.04, context-menu

I've been looking into this for a while now, and no matter which .desktop file I look into, I can't change the Ubuntu file explorer "new documents" contextual menu.

So I have chinese translated WPS launchers, but not a simple text editor. A [possible solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1242694/200996) here doesn't work.

Can somebody point me on the right direction, please?

Answer (score 0):

The app specific right click contextual menu is defined in the `.desktop` launcher file of the application, which is effectively in use. On a system, multiple launchers with the same name may exist. Only one will be used. Only changes in that specific `.desktop` file will have effect.

`.desktop` launchers on your system matching the label you see in the Application Overviews or in your menu system (other Ubuntu flavours) can be found with a `find` command:

```
find / -name '*.desktop' -exec grep -H "Name=<what you see in the menu>" {} \; 2>/dev/null
```

Only `.desktop` launchers existing in an `applications` directory can be in effect. If you find multiple results, you already can discard those for which the directory path does not end with `applications`.

Then, for the remaining ones, a `.desktop` file residing under your home folder in `~/.local/share/applications` will take precedence. Otherwise, precedence is determined by the order in which the parent directories of `applications` are listed in the variable `XDG_DATA_DIRS`

```
$ printenv XDG_DATA_DIRS
/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
```

Thus, a `.desktop` file living in `/usr/share/gnome/applications` will take precedence over a file with the same name in `/usr/local/share/applications`, etc.

Comment: Thanks. Is the -H working with a sort of grep functionality? I get some results, but a: those are found in the timeshift folder and b) the description in in plain english which is fine (I instead want to get rid of Chinese labels)

Comment: That find command allows to specifically find these .desktop files that would display what you currently see in the application overview. What is displayed there is what is after `Name=` in the corresponding .desktop file. So a good seach should retrieve results, at least one. The active one is where you can edit right-click menu options.

Comment: so to recap, I use the printenv and take the first directory, and then search with the find above? Though the find above looks from the root onward. Sorry, but I must be missing something.

Comment: I will elaborate that part a little more in my answer